# Check more than one conditions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

I have a form to fill, I want to check if all the textboxes are empty if they are then show asterisks beside the empty ones, if not (they are full of info) alert the page saved.

The checking part and showing asterisks is working the saving part isn't working for me.

```
function txtchk(tbox, asterisk, f, name) { //the f parameter is an empty paragraph
        var bol = Boolean;
        if (bol === true) {
            if (document.getElementById(tbox).value == "") {
                document.getElementById(asterisk).style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById(f).innerHTML = name + " required";
                document.getElementById(f).style.display = "block";                  
                return bol = true;

            }
            else {
                document.getElementById(asterisk).style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById(f).style.display = "none";
                return bol = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            alert ("saved");
        }
    }

    function combiner() {
        txtchk("tbox1", "asterisk1", "f1", "Product Name");
        txtchk("tbox2", "asterisk2", "f2", "Description");
        txtchk("tbox3", "asterisk3", "f3", "Image");
        txtchk("tbox4", "asterisk4", "f4", "Unit Price");
        txtchk("tbox5", "asterisk5", "f5", "ISBN");
        txtchk("tbox6", "asterisk6", "f6", "Author");
        txtchk("tbox7", "asterisk7", "f7", "Amount in the stock");
        txtchk("tbox8", "asterisk8", "f8", "Color");
        txtchk("ops", "asterisk9", "f9", "Size");
        txtchk("tbox10", "asterisk10", "f10", "Manufacturer");
        txtchk("tbox11", "asterisk11", "f11", "Amount in the stock");
    }
```

This function in called by a button (on click)

Comment: `var bol = Boolean; if (bol...` this will always be true.

Comment: @LucaKiebel `if(bol)` will be evaluated to true, but `if(bol === true)` resolves to false. Just tried it in my Chrome dev tools. Your point remains true though, this if statement will always resolve to the same value..

Comment: @AnisR. You're right, that seems to be the problem

Comment: so what is the best practise ?

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you have the following `if` condition:

```
var bol = Boolean;

if (bol === true) {
        //do something
    }
    else {
        //do something else
    }
```

The issue with this is that the value of `bol` will always be the same (an object), and therefore the condition `bol === true` will always evaluate to `false`.

What were you trying to achieve with this specific `if` statement?

Comment: to check if the compiler enters the second if (because tbox .value == "") which will return true to bol, now if it doesnt enter (tbox.value != "") it will return bol to false, then it will continue to the else of the first if and alert the page.

Comment: i think that every time i hit the button the compiler sets the value of bol to true because its on top of everything, which is what i want, or do i?

Comment: Well, if so I believe you should really review how `return` statements work.

Answer (score 0):

See it here...

```js
const checkboxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('label')];
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
   if(!checkboxes.some(i => i.querySelector('input').checked)){
      if(confirm("No checkbox is checked, add '*'?")){
          checkboxes.forEach(i => {
              const star = document.createElement('span');
              star.innerHTML = "*";
              i.appendChild(star);
          })
      }
   } else {
      const selectedCheckboxes = checkboxes.map(i => i.querySelector('input')).filter(i => i.checked).map(i => i.value);
        alert(JSON.stringify(selectedCheckboxes))
        console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedCheckboxes));
      }
});
```

```css
label { display: block; }
```

```html
<h3>Select A choice</h3>
<hr />
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="Choice 1" /> Choice 1 
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="Choice 2" /> Choice 2 
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="Choice 3" /> Choice 3 
</label>
<hr />
<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Perhaps toggle the stars?